# Mathematica Solve[] returns function with variable slots

Tags: vb.net, wolfram-mathematica

When I solve for a high degree polynomial in Wolfram Mathamatica it returns a function with variable slots (the "#1"'s) in it, like this:

```
In[1]:= Solve[p^4 + 4*p^4 (1 - p) + 10*p^4*(1 - p)^2 + 20*p^5*(1 - p)^3 + (
40*p^6*(1 - p)^4)/(1 - 2*p*(1 - p)) == x && 0 < p < 1 && 0 < x < 1, p, Reals]
Out[1]:= {{p -> Root[x - 2 x #1 + 2 x #1^2 - 15 #1^4 + 34 #1^5 - 28 #1^6 + 
   8 #1^7 &, 2]}
```

How can I get it to give me the answer without the variable slots?
It's not as if it needs more information, because if I assign a value to x it will evaluate the expression completely:

```
In[2]:= x=0.7
Out[2]:= 0.7
In[3]:= Root[x - 2 x #1 + 2 x #1^2 - 15 #1^4 + 34 #1^5 - 28 #1^6 + 8 #1^7 &, 2]
Out[3]:= 0.583356
```

The Mathematica help shows this syntax under the reference for `Root[]` but gives no explanation.

I need to use this result in terms of x in a VB program so I need to know how to get rid of the #1's.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_newtons_method.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a mathematical issue than a programming issue.  The fact is that there are plenty of mathematical functions that have roots that cannot be expressed in [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).  The classic example is [the Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), which states that the roots of the general polynomial of degree five or higher cannot be expressed in closed form.  The need to express the roots of such a polynomial is the whole purpose of Mathematica's `Root` object.  Here's a simple example:

```
roots = x /. Solve[x^5 - x - 1 == 0, x]
(* Out: 
  {Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 1], Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 2], 
   Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 3], Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 4], 
   Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 5]}
*)
```

These are *exact* representations of the roots of the polynomial.  They can be estimated to whatever precision you want:

```
N[roots, 20]
(* Out:
  {1.1673039782614186843, 
   -0.76488443360058472603 - 0.35247154603172624932 I, 
   -0.76488443360058472603 + 0.35247154603172624932 I, 
    0.18123244446987538390 - 1.08395410131771066843 I, 
    0.18123244446987538390 + 1.08395410131771066843 I}
*)
```

Now, in your case, you are asking when a rational function of degree 7 in $p$ is equal to $x$.  The answer is

```
Root[x - 2 x #1 + 2 x #1^2 - 15 #1^4 + 34 #1^5 - 28 #1^6 + 8 #1^7 &, 2]
```

This tells you that you need

```
x - 2 x p + 2 x p^2 - 15 p^4 + 34 p^5 - 28 p^6 + 8 p^7 = 0
```

and there is no simpler closed form.  Now, if you set `x=0.7`, or some other decimal approximation, then you'll get a numerical estimate that's good for that particular `x` value.  It's still not a closed form, though.  For comparison, try `x=7/10`.  You should get

```
x=7/10
Root[7 - 14 #1 + 14 #1^2 - 150 #1^4 + 340 #1^5 - 280 #1^6 + 80 #1^7 &, 2]
```

Now, you could certainly write a function `f` using the `Root` object to help you explore what's going on.

```
f[x_] = Root[x - 2 x #1 + 2 x #1^2 - 15 #1^4 + 34 #1^5 - 28 #1^6 + 8 #1^7 &,2];
f[0.7]
(* Out: 0.583356  *)
```

You can even plot it.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]